# Can I create a 13-month Fiscal Year

Tags: custom-fiscal-year

Our company is moving from a Calendar Year to a new FY starting Feb. 1 ending Jan 31. The issue is that for this new year it will cover 13 months (Jan 2018 - Jan 2019) - I can't see a way to account for this in the Custom Fiscal Year settings. Is there a way to do this...am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like very very weird requirement. I highly doubt standard sales force will be able to accomodate it.

Comment: Actually it is a very normal scenario... And I did figure out how to set it up using Custom Fiscal Years and just creating a new Custom Fiscal Year for the first year which includes 13 months.

Comment: I am in the process of doing the exact same change. We are starting the year in January but ending it January 31, so this Fiscal year will have 13 months. Which selection did you make when first configuring the custom year? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg4Gw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg4Gw.png)

Comment: If your fiscal years are 3 months and always start and end on the same days of the months (i.e. the 1st of January and the 31st of March for Q1) then it doesn't matter which of the selections you choose under the "4 Quarters a year..." section.  You will then account for the first 13-month year by creating Custom Fiscal Years and adding weeks to that first fiscal year.

Answer (score 3):

In order to allow for a Fiscal Year to be less or more than 12 months you must use Custom Fiscal Years (highly recommend setting up in Sandbox first!) - Once enabled you will create a new Custom Fiscal Year and set a Start date (e.g. 2/1/2018) and then Add (Insert) the extra month.  The UI is a little confusing but is easy once you figure it out.  Then you can create new Calendar years for subsequent years which will only contain 12 months. You should also add Fiscal years for previous years.  In our case we were going from a Gregorian calendar (Jan. 1 - Dec. 31) to a Fiscal year starting Feb.1 and ending Jan. 31 of the following year.

Adding screenshots which might be helpful:
[image]